# expected { before destructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11

I've got a problem with my newly class called Fountainofyouth. After trying to build whole project debugger shows

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

and
error: `expected '{' before 'Fountainofyouth'`
Can anybody tell me whats going on?
content of Fountainofyouth.cpp:

```
#include "Fountainofyouth.h"

//warning
Fountainofyouth::Fountainofyouth(int startDrinks) : Field
{
    //ctor
}

//error
Fountainofyouth::~Fountainofyouth()
{
    //dtor
}

string Fountainofyouth::fieldType()
{
    return 0;
}

bool Fountainofyouth::canEnter(Unit* unit)
{
    return 0;
}

void Fountainofyouth::affect(Unit* unit)
{

}
```

`

Comment: It would help knowing what's `Field`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor definition shouldn't have `: Field` part:

```
Fountainofyouth::Fountainofyouth(int startDrinks) // : Field <- remove this
{
    //ctor
}
```

If you meant to inherit `Fountainofyouth` from the `Field` then do so in the class's definition, not on its constructor.

```
struct Fountainofyouth : Field
{
    // declaration of ctor, dtor, etc.
};
```

Alternatively, if `Field` is a member of `Fountainofyouth` then to [value initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) add a pair of parenthesis to it:

```
Fountainofyouth::Fountainofyouth(int startDrinks) : Field()
{
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if `Field` is a variable that is trying to default construct it should be: `Fountainofyouth(int startDrinks) : Field() { }`